# Receive multicast using boost asio

Tags: c++, boost, multicast

I have seen a few other related questions on SO, but none that helped solve my problem.

I have the following code:

```
class MulticastReceiver
{
public:

    MulticastReceiver(const String& ip, const UInt16 port)  :
        m_endpoint(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4(), port),
        m_socket(m_service, m_endpoint)
    {
        boost::asio::ip::address addr = boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(ip);
        if (!addr.is_multicast()) throw std::exception("excpeted a multicast address");

        m_socket.set_option(boost::asio::ip::multicast::join_group(addr.to_v4()));
        m_socket.set_option(boost::asio::socket_base::receive_buffer_size(8 * 1024 * 1024));
        m_socket.set_option(boost::asio::socket_base::reuse_address(true));
    }

    size_t receive(void* msg, const size_t size)
    {
        boost::system::error_code error;
        const size_t received = m_socket.receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(msg, size), m_endpoint, 0, error);
        if (error && error != boost::asio::error::message_size)
        {
            throw boost::system::system_error(error);
            return 0;
        }
        return received;
    }

private:

    boost::asio::io_service m_service;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint m_endpoint;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::socket m_socket;

};

// test code
MulticastReceiver recv(ip, port);
char msg[2000];
while (true)
{
    const size_t size = recv.receive(&msg[0], 2000);
    cout << "Received a message sized: " << size << endl;
}
```

Everything works perfect if sending and receiving from the same server, however, if I send from a different server, the packets are not received. Using Wireshark, I can see that all the packets arrive on the interface expected, with the multicast address and port expected.

Note: the receiving server is Windows and have tested sending from both Windows and Linux if it matters.

Any ideas why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the service connecting to all interfaces?

Comment: likely a firewall- or general routing problem.

Comment: @kometen In the case of my tests, there is only 1 network card per server, and using monitoring tools in Windows and Linux, that interface is being used (as opposed to the loopback or other internal interface)

Comment: Try setting the [TTL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__multicast__hops.html) to a bigger number? It's not clear what the default is.

Comment: @MarkWaterman While not in the code example, I have tested the TTL and various sizes for my tests. The servers are connected directly to a smart switch, so 1 would have been sufficient, Like I said in the post, the data arrives on the receiving server according to Wireshark, my receiver in C++ isn't getting it though